# Change color of theme in DialogFragment with API10

Tags: android, styles, android-dialogfragment

I have a dialogFragment which works well, in api 11+, it appears with the HOLO_LIGHT theme.
THe thing is with API 10, the dialogfragment is dark and I want it light so that my dark icon display well.

I can't use HOLO_LIGHT because it needs API 11+
I have tried to change it but it never want to work.

Here is the minimal code :

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            AddCommentDialog testDialog = new AddCommentDialog();
            testDialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.MyFragment);
            testDialog.show(fm, "fragment_name");       
        }
    });
}
}
```

AddCommentDialog :

```
public class AddCommentDialog extends DialogFragment {
// private final String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

private Context context;

public AddCommentDialog() {
    // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContext(getActivity());

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, 0);

    AlertDialog.Builder principal = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    principal.setTitle(R.string.report);
    View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.add_comment, null);

    principal.setView(view);

    AlertDialog ad = principal.create();
    return ad;

}

public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

}

And styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light"></style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme"></style>

<style name="MyFragment">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I don't publish the add_comment.xml because the color of the dialogFragment is independant of his content.

Comment: How could you use DialogFragment with API10?